Simple arbitrage pricing of bond option

This is Tuckman fixed income security textbook. The text here is trying to price a 990 six month call on a six month zero bond. When we replicate the portfolio, where is the F_.5 coming from?
My understanding is that the underlying is the F_1. Why we are adding F_.5 in the equation but not anything else?

The underlying is indeed the F_1.  But the F_0.5 is required to determine the forward yield.  Ie at what yield the F_1 is expected to trade at after 6 months.
